# Searchbar with core data issues

Tags: swift, core-data, uisearchbar

I have a search bar.And  data displayed in labels with scrollview.

For ex:

core data Fields :

1.id
2.company
3.Employe Name

4.Address

If i type  id,company or Employee Name in searchbar i want to dispaly associated results.

my code :

For search data :

```
  func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

       var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agency")
     request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
      var   countResult : NSArray   = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!



    let result  = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@",searchText)


    self.filtered = self.countResult.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(result!)



    if (filtered.count == 0 ) {
        searchActive = false;
    }else {
        searchActive = true;
    }

   println(filtered)

}
```

It shows an error    " 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection".

These codes cannot satisfy what i want.And also i dont have a idea how to fetch the related rows according to enter value in search bar.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this a runtime error? If it, is I've got a pretty good idea what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is your predicate - you're trying to use `CONTAINS` on an `NSManagedObject` subclass, but `CONTAINS` only works with `String`. To check whether your search text is contained within any of your managed objects you need to evaluate whether it is contained in each attribute (in your case `id`, `company` and `empolyeeName`, I'm assuming they're all `String`s).

To do this you should change your predicate to:

```
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id BEGINSWITH %@ OR
                                           company BEGINSWITH %@ OR
                                           employeeName BEGINSWITH %@", 
                                           searchText, searchText, searchText)
```

I would recommend using `BEGINSWITH` instead of `CONTAINS[c]` since when searching your user is likely to be entering the first part of the phrase. Also, as Apple said in their 2013 WWDC talk *Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging* -

> ...we've got begins with and ends with and that's by far the cheapest query that you can execute.
>
> ...
>
> Contains is more expensive because we have to work along and see
>   whether it contains...

And in the case of a search, you want it to be fast!

Secondly, you don't need to filter your results **after** getting them back from CoreData. You can set the `predicate` property on your `NSFetchRequest` and your returned results will be filtered. For example:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Agency")
request.predicate = // Your predicate...

let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error)
// Now do what you need with the results.
```

A final note, it's best not to force unwrap your results from `executeRequest` in case there is some problem and `nil` is returned - in that case your app would crash. You could instead use:

```
if let unwrappedResults = results {
    // Now do what you want with the unwrapped results.
}
```

Comment: Am using labels for populate that result data  instead of tableview.Can you please give me example code for that.

Comment: The code above should work fine with that. You should be using the unwrappedResults to populate the labels. Is there a specific reason you're not using a UITableView though?

Comment: yes, when i use this code if let unwrappedResults = results {
  
} shows a compie error that is " Pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression".

Comment: I've never had that error before. After doing a little research though a possible reason for it could be that you've included parenthesis around  if you if let` statement? For example - `if (let unwrappedResults = results) { }`

Comment: without parenthesis go the error " Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type".I think because of  let

Comment: without that line i got the output not yet crash

Comment: That error is because your `results` aren't optional. Are you still force unwrapping them with `!` (like on the fourth line of your code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74910/discussion-between-lyida-and-abakersmith).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has something to do with your use of `SELF` in the predicate format, and the "collection" referred to in the error message is the controller sub/class within which your code resides.

Try something like this (forgive me I'm Obj-C not Swift so may have the syntax incorrect).

```
let searchAttribute = <<entity.attribute key path>>
let result = NSPredicate(format:"%K CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchAttribute, searchText)
```

Where %K refers to the key path, that in the case of Core Data is your entity attribute. For example: `Agency.name` if that attribute exists for your Agency object.

Read about [Predicate Format String Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

---

UPDATE after third comment...

In my apps my solution includes the creation of a custom method in an extension of the Core Data generated `NSManagedObject` subclass. If that sounds like you know what I mean, let me know and I will post details.

In the meantime, create a custom method in whatever class your `UISearchBar` is controlled... (apologies Obj-C not Swift)

```
- (NSString *)searchKey {
    NSString *tempSearchKey = nil;

    NSString *searchAtrribute1 = Agency.attribute1;
    NSString *searchAtrribute2 = Agency.attribute2;
    NSString *searchAtrribute3 = Agency.attribute3;
    NSString *searchAtrribute4 = Agency.attribute4;

    tempSearchKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@", searchAtrribute1, searchAtrribute2, searchAtrribute3, searchAtrribute4];

    return tempSearchKey;
}
```

You'll obviously need a strong reference for your `Agency` entity object to persist within the class, otherwise you will need to embed this bit of code into your `searchBar` function.

Work OK?

Comment: Nice, but i have more than 11 fields.

Comment: More than 11 attributes for the one entity?

Comment: yes, but i want to predicate only 3 so how the code change,

Comment: refer to update - deals with 4 - if you only require 3 then drop one out.

Comment: but did it answer your question?

Comment: No , but your suggestion helps me to find an answer.

ABakerSmith answer was relevant to my problem.